# How could i make pagination with button and swiper in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable, react-native-swiper

I tried to do with `ScrollView` and `transform` and `scrollTo` but i couldnt figure it out and i dont want to create with `react-navigation`

i want to create a fixed bar at the top and two animated buttons in it and when button touched go second screen and play button animation and when screen swiped play button animation also

like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRt7XIQoAO0) and screen has to be slideable too